# how to transform a matrix in a **hypergraph** of an object of class network

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like below that is a hyper graph matrix, I transformed it to the object network , but I dunno how can I  transform this matrix in a **hypergraph** of an object of class network, can you help me? any idea?

```
mat<-as.matrix(data)
g<- as.network.matrix(mat)
g
```

```
         E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 E10 E11 E12 E13 E14
EVELYN     1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0
LAURA      1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   0
THERESA    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0   0   0   0   0
BRENDA     1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   0
CHARLOTTE  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
FRANCES    0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0
ELEANOR    0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   0   0
PEARL      0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0
RUTH       0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1   0   0   0   0   0
VERNE      0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   0   0   1   0   0
MYRA       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   0
KATHERINE  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   0   1   1   1
SYLVIA     0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   0   1   1   1
NORA       0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   1   1   1   1   1
HELEN      0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0   1   1   1   0   0
DOROTHY    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0
OLIVIA     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   1   0   0   0
FLORA      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `mat` is a incidence matrix,  and I am not sure if you are looking for something like below if you are using `network` package

```
as.matrix(network(t(mat)),matrix.type = "incidence")
```

---

Besides, the incidence matrix visualization via `igraph` can be achieved from the following:

```
g <- igraph::graph_from_incidence_matrix(mat)
```

then

```
plot(g)
```

gives
[image]

**DATA**

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(18L, 
14L), .Dimnames = list(c("EVELYN", "LAURA", "THERESA", "BRENDA", 
"CHARLOTTE", "FRANCES", "ELEANOR", "PEARL", "RUTH", "VERNE", 
"MYRA", "KATHERINE", "SYLVIA", "NORA", "HELEN", "DOROTHY", "OLIVIA", 
"FLORA"), c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", 
"E10", "E11", "E12", "E13", "E14")))
```

Comment: @elham Does this address your question?

Comment: yes thank you ,I also used anther method , but the result is the same,

Comment: at the beginning i was confused because, I didnt know how to plot hypergraph ...

Comment: @elham That's great! If you think my answer helps, please feel free upvote or accept it, thanks!